# Closed form expression of oscillatory integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm trying to find an analytical expression for

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{i (a_{0}+a_{1}z+a_{2}z^{2}+a_{3}z^{3}+a_{4}z^{4}+a_{5}z^{5})}dz$$ where the coefficients are all real.

```
Integrate[Exp[I*(a0 + a1 z + a2 z^2 + a3 z^3 + a4 z^4 + a5 z^5)], {z, -Infinity, Infinity}, Assumptions -> {a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5} \[Element] Reals]
```

Mathematica finds a closed form expression for the integral with a third order polynomial in z as the exponent but I couldn't find one for the fifth order polynomial-- Mathematica just doesn't perform the integral. It could be that it requires extra assumptions, but I'm not sure what exactly. Any help regarding how to proceed would be appreciated.
TIA!

Comment: Your words " Mathematica finds a closed form expression for the integral with a third order polynomial in z as the exponent" do not correspond to reality:  in 13.1 on Windows 10 `Integrate[Exp[I*(1 + x + x^2 + x^3)], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]` returns the input.

Comment: It's strange that `Integrate[Exp[I*(a + b*x + c*x^2)], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> {a, b, c} \[Element] Reals]` results in `(c E^(I a - (I b^2)/(4 c)) Sqrt[\[Pi]/2] (I + Sign[c]))/Abs[c]^(3/2)` which is in accordance with `NIntegrate[Exp[I*(1 + x + x^2)], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]`.

Comment: Posting the integral in both TeX and Mathematica code makes it more likely someone will copy-paste it & try to help.

Comment: @user64494 Yeah, it's a little weird. But Mathematica does give an output for `Integrate[Exp[I*(x^3+ p x)],{x,-Infinity,Infinity},Assumptions->Element[{p},Reals]`